# php login pdo update

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

So I'm trying to move to PDO connection but i'm currently really stuck. Need some helping hands right now. Included both - my login.php and my class file. Also I know MD5 is not safe at all, in process to fix that as well.
Thank you.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

  $object = new Login();
  $object->verifyDatabase();

  if($object->isLoggedIn())
     header('location: index.php');
  else
    $object->showErrors();

}
$token = $_SESSION['token'] = md5(uniqid(mt_rand(),true));
?>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">
    Username: <input type="text" name="username"/>
    Password: <input type="password" name="password"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo $token;?>" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login"/>
```

```
<?php
include_once('class.mysql.php');

class Login {

  private $_id;
  private $_username;
  private $_password;
  private $_passmd5;

  private $_errors;
  private $_access;
  private $_login;
  private $_token;
  private $db;

  public function __construct() {
    $this->_errors = array();
    $this->_login  = isset($_POST['login'])? 1 : 0;
    $this->_access = 0;
    $this->_token  = $_POST['token'];

    $this->_id       = 0;
    $this->_username = ($this->_login)? $this->filter($_POST['username']) : $_SESSION['username'];
    $this->_password = ($this->_login)? $this->filter($_POST['password']) : '';
    $this->_passmd5  = ($this->_login)? md5($this->_password) : $_SESSION['password'];
    $this->db = new Connection();
    $this->db = $this->db->dbConnect();
  }

  public function isLoggedIn() {
    ($this->_login)? $this->verifyPost() : $this->verifySession();

    return $this->_access;
  }

  public function filter($var) {
    return preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/','',$var);
  }

  public function verifyPost() {
    try {
      if(!$this->isTokenValid())
         throw new Exception('Invalid Form Submission');

      if(!$this->isDataValid())
         throw new Exception('Invalid Form Data');

      if(!$this->verifyDatabase())
         throw new Exception('Invalid Username/Password');

    $this->_access = 1;
    $this->registerSession();
    }
    catch(Exception $e) {
      $this->_errors[] = $e->getMessage();
    }
  }

  public function verifySession() {
    if($this->sessionExist() && $this->verifyDatabase())
       $this->_access = 1;
  }
  /////Old verifyDatabase/////
  ///////////////////////////////
  //public function verifyDatabase() {

  //mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());
  //mysql_select_db("example") or die(mysql_error());

  //$data = mysql_query("SELECT ID FROM users WHERE username = '{$this->_username}' AND password = '{$this->_passmd5}'");

  //if(mysql_num_rows($data))
  //  {
  //    list($this->_id) = @array_values(mysql_fetch_assoc($data));
  //    return true;
  //  }
  //else
  //  { return false; }
  //}

  public function verifyDatabase() {
        $st = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='{$this->_username}' AND password='{$this->_password}'");
        $st->bindParam(1, $this->_username);
        $st->bindParam(2, $this->_password);
        $st->execute();

        if($st->rowCount() == 1) {
            echo "User verified";
        } else {
            echo "Incorrect username or password";
        }
  }

  public function isDataValid() {
    return (preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9]{5,12}$/',$this->_username) && preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9]{5,12}$/',$this->_password))? 1 : 0;
  }

  public function isTokenValid() {
    return (!isset($_SESSION['token']) || $this->_token != $_SESSION['token'])? 0 : 1;
  }

  public function registerSession() {
    $_SESSION['ID'] = $this->_id;
    $_SESSION['username'] = $this->_username;
    $_SESSION['password'] = $this->_passmd5;
  }

  public function sessionExist() {
    return (isset($_SESSION['username']) && isset($_SESSION['password']))? 1 : 0;
  }

  public function showErrors() {
    echo "<h3>Errors</h3>";

    foreach($this->_errors as $key=>$value)
      echo $value."<br>";
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: The session token looks fine since its unique and only if you know your sessions are secure it should be fine. You might want to make session token a array (if a user opens several pages and submits a older page it will be invalid because it was overridden) and maybe add a expire variable. `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` shouldn't be used use: `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']`

Comment: Your `verifyDatabase()` method `bindParam` is wrong change the values in the query to `?`

Comment: your password check is kinda weak. you might want to allow any character/have a 2 upper/special/number and not limit the max

Comment: 1) You should never use superglobals like `$_POST` within a class. Instead pass it as a parameter 2) Constructor **should never** do too much work. It should only init the state. Nothing more.

Comment: and also learn about Dependency Injection and SRP

Comment: oh yeah, also `md5()` hash algorithm should not be used in new applications anymore. You'd use `hash('sha256', $string)` instead

Answer (score 1):

The query syntax with parameters is incorrect. If you are using positional parameters, then you need to write the query as follow:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=? AND password=?
```